# Using nested for loop and range to print the desired display in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was given a problem where I was asked to  write a function that uses a nested loop and the range function to print out the following display:

```
SD1, SD2, SD3, SD4, SD5, SD6,
HD1, HD2, HD3, HD4, HD4, HD6, HD7, HD8, HD9, HD10, HD11,
CD1, CD2, CD3, CD4
```

I know how I would use a for loop and range to print each line, but I am not sure how I could use a nested loop to print the desired display. We haven't learned about dictionaries yet, and we have only really covered how to use lists.

I know I can do the following to print the first line, but using a nested loop to print the rest doesn't seem logical to me. Before emailing the instructor, I thought it would be best to ask here for pointers in case I am missing something. Any suggestions?

```
for i in range(1, 7):
    print(f'SD{i},', end=' ')
print('')
for i in range(1,12):
    print(f'HD{i},' end=' ')
print('')
for i in range(1,5):
    print(f'CD{i},' end=' ')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use OrderDict to save the input format, that way your insertion order would be preserved. Just add a loop over the code you have written. Like the example below

```
from collections import OrderedDict
type_of_string = OrderedDict({'SD': 7,'HD': 12,'CD': 5})
for key,value in type_of_string.items():
    for i in range(value):
        print(key + str(i), end=', ')
    print()
```

**EDIT**
Using only list:

```
type_of_string = [['SD', 7],['HD', 11],['CD', 5]]
for a in type_of_string:
    for i in range(a[1]):
        print(a[0] + str(i), end=', ')
    print()
```

Comment: This answer also works, thanks a bunch. I am going with yours because it is the 'easiest' way to get it done although it isn't time efficient. Thanks for the help.

Comment: glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
In [1]: idx_dict = {'SD': 6, 'HD': 11, 'CD': 4}

In [2]: for letter, idx in idx_dict.items():
    ...:     print(', '.join(f'{letter}{i+1}' for i in range(int(idx))))

SD1, SD2, SD3, SD4, SD5, SD6
HD1, HD2, HD3, HD4, HD5, HD6, HD7, HD8, HD9, HD10, HD11
CD1, CD2, CD3, CD4
```

If you need to use nested loops more explicitly, you could do this:

```
for letter, idx in idx_dict.items():
    output = []
    for i in range(int(idx)):
        output.append(f'{letter}{i+1}')
    print(', '.join(output))
```

Here's a way to do it without using a dicitonary:

```
In [20]: letters = ['SD', 'HD', 'CD']

In [21]: max_indexes = [6, 11, 4]

In [22]: for letter, max_idx in zip(letters, max_indexes):
    ...:     output = []
    ...:     for i in range(max_idx):
    ...:         output.append(f'{letter}{i+1}')
    ...:     print(', '.join(output))
```

If you don't want to use the `zip` function, then you can do it using `enumerate`:

```
In [23]: for idx, letter in enumerate(letters):
    ...:     output = []
    ...:     for i in range(max_indexes[idx]):
    ...:         output.append(f'{letter}{i+1}')
    ...:     print(', '.join(output))
```

Comment: That does work, but we haven't learned about dictionaries yet so I don't think I can use them. I really don't see how I can get the desired display using lists and nested for loops.

Comment: Thanks for all the different ways. I've learned a lot. I didn't think about using two different lists.

Answer (score 1):

Or an one-liner:

```
lot=[('SD',6), ('HD',11), ('CD',4)]
print('\n'.join(', '.join([x+str(i) for i in range(1,y+1)]) for x,y in lot))
```

Output:

```
SD1, SD2, SD3, SD4, SD5, SD6
HD1, HD2, HD3, HD4, HD5, HD6, HD7, HD8, HD9, HD10, HD11
CD1, CD2, CD3, CD4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
first_letters = ['S', 'H', 'C']
line_lengths = [7, 12, 5]

for i in range(3):
    for j in range(line_lengths[i]):
        print(first_letters[i] + 'D' + str(j) + ',', end = ' ')
    print()
```

You were missing the logic where the outer loop was to run each row and the nested loop is for each element on a row. Hope this helps. Solved only using lists and nested loop.

Comment: Thanks, your explanation definitely helped. Why not just initiate the first_letters list as ['SD', 'HD', 'CD']? The concatenation isn't really necessary right?

Comment: Yes that's also a way to do, I just put it like that just to isolate the part of the letters that was changing.